# jQuery - merge two arrays with alteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, merge

Im trying to find simplest way to merge two arrays into the third one, with jQuery, like this:

```
[A,B,C,D]
[1,2,3,4]
```

The answer would be:

```
[A,1,B,2,C,3,D,4]
```

Another example:

```
[A,B,C] + [1,2,3,4,5] = [A,1,B,2,C,3,4,5]
[A,B,C,D] + [1,2,3] = [A,1,B,2,C,3,D]
```

Comment: will they always be the same length?

Comment: What should happen in one array is longer than the other ?

Comment: @MattBall I'm using nth-child sorting with some ugly calculations :)

Comment: @arnaud576875 [A,B] + [1,2,3,4] = [A,1,B,2,3,4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly create an Array using the [`jQuery.map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method. When you return an Array, `jQuery.map` does a `.concat()`.

This will also prevent holes in the Array when lengths differ.

http://jsfiddle.net/zbCj7/

```
var chars = ['A','B','C','D'];
var nums = [1,2,3,4];

var res = $.map( chars.length > nums.length ? chars : nums, function(v,i) {
    var chr = chars[i];
    var num = nums[i];
    if( chr !== undefined && num !== undefined ) {
        return [chr,num];
    } else if( chr === undefined ) {
        return num;
    } else {
        return chr;
    }
});
```

or a little more concise:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbCj7/1/

```
var chars = ['A','B','C','D'];
var nums = [1,2];

var res = $.map( chars.length > nums.length ? chars : nums, function(v,i) {
    var chr = chars[i];
    var num = nums[i];
    return ( chr !== undefined && num !== undefined ) ?
        [chr,num] : ( chr === undefined ) ? num : chr;
});
```

---

If you *really* want to make it concise, you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbCj7/2/

```
var chars = ['A','B','C','D'];
var nums = [1,2];

var res = $.map( chars.length > nums.length ? chars : nums, function(v,i) {
    return [ chars[i], nums[i] ].slice( chars[i]===undefined,
                                        nums[i]===undefined || 2 );
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var result = [];
var a = ['A','B','C','D'];
var b = [1,2,3,4];

$.each(a, function (index, value) {
    result.push(value);
    result.push(b[index]);
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GcTx7/3/

Without jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; ++i) {
    result.push(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

This one takes care of the case when the two arrays do not have the same length:

```
for (var i = 0, l = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < l; ++i) {
    if (i < a.length) result.push(a[i]);
    if (i < b.length) result.push(b[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GcTx7/1/

Comment: If `a.length > b.length` this will push `undefined`s into `result`, which I strongly doubt is the desired behavior.

Comment: This is undefined behavior :)

Comment: Great start. Thank you! Can you help with different length arrays?

Comment: Added with handling of different lengths

Comment: Use the proper generic `$.each()`. It isn't supported behavior to pass an Array of non-elements to `$()`.

Comment: @350D: You simply call the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method with the collection as the first argument, and the function as the second. `$.each( arr, fn )`. This is built for iterating/enumerating various types of collections instead of just jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is a great array sorting experience for me!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that using jquery is :

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = ['a','b','c'];
var merged_array = mergeArray([a,b]);

function mergeArrays(arrayOfArray) {
    var result = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArray.length;i++ ) {
        $.merge(result, arrayOfArray[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This way you can merge as many arrays u want without worrying about the size of individual array.

Hope this helps out as well.